Win10: Use powershell Compress-Archive command to create .zip excluding some directories in subdirectories in batch file
I have a batch file with the next content:
@echo off
SetLocal

echo Enter path to save release archive (Block.zip):
set /p ch=


cd %~dp0\setup
Powershell -Command "& { Get-ChildItem -exclude "Block\source", "setup.py" | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath %ch%\BlocSetup.zip }"


echo Archive created at "%ch%\BlocSetup.zip"
pause

I want to exclude one subfolder %~dp0\setup\Block\source and the file %~dp0\setup\setup.py from the archive. But it doesnt work- the folder exists in the archive created.
